# Spring Jdbc mapping rows

Tags: spring

How can i map rows of two tables that refers each other?
For example there are Employee and Department tables. Employee has a reference to department model which is the department of the employee and Department has a reference to employee model which is the manager of the department. So how can i do map rows using spring RowMapper.

Thanks,

Comment: `RowMapper` works on resultsets, not tables.  You need to write the correct SQL, and then map the flat resultset any way you choose.

Answer (score 1):

> How can i map rows of two tables that refers each other?

for example like this:

```
public class TwoTablesRowMapper implements RowMapper<Map<String, Object>> {

  /**
   * Map data from select over 2 tables e.g.:
   * 
   * select 
   *    A.foo as afoo, 
   *    B.bar as bbar
   * from PARENT A, 
   *      CHILD B
   * where A.ID = B.ID
   * 
   * 
   * @param rs
   * @param rowNum
   * @return
   * @throws SQLException 
   */
  public Map<String, Object> mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
      Map<String, Object> resultMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();

      // instead of a map one could fill an object
      // e.g.: myObject.set.afoo(afoo)
      resultMap.put("afoo", rs.getString("afoo"));
      resultMap.put("bbar", rs.getString("bbar"));

      return resultMap;
  }
}
```

for the SQL part i recommend you create a new question with specific SQL details (tables, relations, etc.) and tagged sql, it should find more (sql-savvy) viewers this way

Comment: Thanks, this is applicable for small domain objects where relationship is not much complex. But actually i want every model class to have its own mapper class. For example: The Employee model has a reference to Department and while populating the domain model i need the Employee class to ask for Department Mapper class for the referenced department instance which is based on the department id. And the vice versa. This is to mean am trying to have the functionality i get from ORM tools like EJB.

Comment: Unless i do this mapping i could not use like Employee emp = something; and call as emp.getDepartment().getDepartmentName(); or emp.getDepartment().getManager().firstName(); Please, would you suggest me the right way to do this.

Comment: basically you choose either self programmed mapping or ORM, which is the right way ? depends on your requirements, performance, expected lifetime of implementation, expected changes etc. if you have more than one of those mappings - i would go ORM (JPA2 with Hibernate, TopLink and friends), but you will need ORM knowledge, there are just other pitfalls on the ORM side :-)